# Suitable forecasting methods for time series in r

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

For my thesis, I want to forecast the monthly sales. I got data of 6 years, and I already aggregated them on a monthly level, resulting in 72 observations, log transformed. This is the time series object I've obtained:

```
       Jan      Feb      Mar      Apr      May      Jun      Jul      Aug      Sep
2015 13.98099 13.86707 13.81279 14.02648 14.27674 14.21412 14.23395 13.96988 14.00624
2016 14.21634 14.00704 14.05400 14.07606 14.20586 14.46138 14.15234 14.31417 13.91900
2017 13.99490 13.90824 14.27708 14.18750 14.06222 14.16077 14.37957 14.36630 14.19188
2018 14.15049 14.20557 13.98271 14.11799 14.32094 14.29468 13.70276 13.72892 13.63643
2019 14.20824 14.17138 13.97853 14.17452 14.26461 14.42239 14.26317 14.20839 14.23635
2020 14.27536 14.18145 14.20229 14.34402 14.20171 14.40331 13.86791 14.01569 13.81158
          Oct      Nov      Dec
2015 13.91717 14.20881 14.32082
2016 14.17202 14.06676 14.28792
2017 14.20140 14.14538 14.15510
2018 13.83971 13.81324 13.77738
2019 14.40160 14.55175 14.43041
2020 14.32758 13.79917 13.95856
```

I've decomposed the time series using a SEATS decomposition to inspect the series:
[SEATS decomposition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBW0U.png). This plot suggests that there is a trend component, as well as a seasonal component in the series - and that the time series is non-stationary.

I've run an `adf.test`, and this resulted in p-value greater than 0.05, indicating that the series is non-stationary. However, the `kpss`test resulted in a p-value far greater than 0.05, indicating that the time series is stationary. So I'm a bit confused here. Furthermore, I've run the command `auto.arima`, and this suggested to use an `ARIMA(1,0,2) with non-zero mean` model. However, the forecast obtained using this model doesn't fit.

So: could anybody help me in finding an appropriate forecasting model for this time series?

Comment: This book is an excellent resource if you would like to know more about forecasting in R: https://otexts.com/fpp2/

Comment: I would suggest the new version otexts.com/fpp3